# Angular Project: Hibernate doesn't create table automatically

Tags: javascript, hibernate

This is my code, I have tried all ways but I see that the customer table is not created. What can it be?

Customer.java

```js
package crudapp.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    @Column
    private String firstname;
    
    @Column
    private String lastname;

    @Column
    private String address;
    
    @Column
    private int age;
    
    ...
    
    protected Customer() {}
    
    public Customer(String firstname, String lastname, String address, int age) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("id=%d, firstname='%s', lastname'%s', address=%s, age=%d", 
                                id, firstname, lastname, address, age); 
    }
}
```

application.properties

```js
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I also tried to use update instead of create in *spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create* but the problem persists.

This is the first project in Angular, I thank everyone who will help me.

Comment: This is the Java Project. Not Angular.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL ok ok, i corrected

Answer (score 0):

I solved; the problem was that the main method was in a different package.